# How do we correctly click on a link or button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm using the PHP + Ajax version of this template: `http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/`, Codeception WebDriver (Selenium) to perform my tests. Most of them are working fine, but I have some random, yes, random!, failing tests, so I always get back to them and try to harden, hoping it will not randomly fail sometime in the future. One of the failing reasons are usually due to wrong clicks on the interface. I tell Codeception to click the #element-id and when it fails, I see that it actually had a different page showing in the output png, but the link activated showing it tried to click the correct link. Sometimes I just have to load a different page before clicking that particular link and wait 10 seconds for it to render, and it works, silly huh? Yeah, but sometimes this doesn't work either.

This is how I used to test things:

```
$I->click('#element-id');
```

And I have to use the element id, because it's a multi-language app, all (mostly) strings come from a strings file and they might change at some point and break tests.

After too many random tests failing, I decided to make the frontend itself responsible for clicking things during tests, it's a long and silly circunventing shot, but it should be work, so I created a functionalHelper:

```
public function clickElement($element)
{
    $I = $this->getDriver();

    $I->executeJS("clickElement('{$element}');");
}
```

And two Javascript functions:

```
function clickElement(element)
{
    element = jQuery(element);

    if(typeof element !== undefined)
    {
        fakeClick(element[0]);
    }

    return true;
}

function fakeClick(object)
{
    if (object.click)
    {
        object.click();
    }
    else if(document.createEvent)
    {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        var allowDefault = object.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```

I'm using jQuery in the first one because it's already available in the template and it's easier to select non-id'ed things.

This is working fine, and you can test it yourself by

1) Opening the page:

```
http://192.241.236.31/themes/preview/smartadmin/1.5/ajaxversion/
```

2) Loading the script in your browser console by executing

```
loadScript('https://www.dropbox.com/s/kuh22fjjsa8zq0i/app.js?dl=1');
```

3) And clicking things:

Calendar

```
clickElement($x('//*[@id="left-panel"]/nav/ul/li[7]/a/span'));
```

Widgets

```
clickElement($x('//*[@id="left-panel"]/nav/ul/li[8]/a/span'));
```

Because the template is using the hash character to control the ajax part of the page and not reload everything, I had to (programatically) add the referer-url to all my href links, so I could, in my app, redirect back to the referer, as the hash part uf the accessed url is not sent to the server. This is a link example:

```
<a href="/users?referer-href-url=/dashboard" title="Users" id="users-navigation">
    <span class="menu-item-parent">Users</span>
</a>
```

Wich basically means the user was looking at the dashboard when she clicked the users link. If something wrong happens, the app will redirect the user back to the dashboard, with an error message.

The problem is that, somehow, during tests, the current url, when tested using:

```
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/#/clients?referer-href-url=/clients');
```

Becomes

```
/#/clients
```

Instead of

```
/#/clients?referer-href-url=/clients
```

This happens **sometimes**, because some other it also works. If I browse the site manually it works in 100% of the time and I always see the correct URL in the address bar. And if I manually execute `clickElement()` it also works fine. The problem only heppens my my suite is running.

Here's an example of it passing (green):

[image]

And the exact same test randomly failing (red):

[image]

This is the code related to the failing test:

```
$I->clickElement('#clients-navigation');

$I->waitForText('Jane Doe', 10);

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/#/clients?referer-href-url=/clients');
```

I usually wait for something after a click, so the page can have time to render.

You can also see that there are a lot of "**I click element**", using those PHP and Javascript functions without a problem.

I'm using:

```
Ubuntu 14.04
PHP 5.5.9
Codeception 2.0.7
Selenium 2.44.0 
Firefox 33.0
```

So, what could be the problem here?
Is this the correct way to click an element in Javascript?

In the process I also experience tests which does not fail when ran singly and fails when in batch, but this might be a different question, right?

Comment: Have you tried a little bit of throttling yet?  Actual users never click as fast as an automated test is capable of.  Are the batch tests properly isolated from each other?

Comment: Since my pages can take a while to render, coming from server, I usually have something like `$I->waitForText('Jane Doe', 10);` after every click.

Comment: Is it possible there needs to be a short amount of "settling time" after that?  Have a look at https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium+clicks+fail+randomly and see if some of those suggestions help.  Let us know if any of them do.

Comment: Comments in this post shows exactly the kind of problems I'm having with those guys: http://googletesting.blogspot.com.br/2009/06/my-selenium-tests-arent-stable.html